# Dynamically populated select element will take the value of the first option but not display the text of it

Tags: javascript, html

```
   window.onload = function()
{
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', init, false);
    init();
}

function init()
{
   populateItem();
}

function populateItem()
{
    clearItem();
    var itemSel = document.getElementById("itemSelect");
    var x = 0;
    for(i=0; i<items.length; i++)
        {

            if(document.getElementById('itemType').value == items[i].Device)


                    {
                        itemSel.innerHTML +="<option value='" + items[i].Model + "'>"+items[i].Make + " " + items[i].Model+"</option>";
                    }
        }
    reload();

}

function clearItem()
{
    for(var ex=document.getElementById('itemSelect').length; ex >= 0; ex--)
        {
            document.getElementById('itemSelect').remove(ex);

        }

}

function reload()
{
    var container = document.getElementById("itemSelect");
    var content = container.innerHTML;
    container.innerHTML= content;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />

    <!--<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" /> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/InventoryItems.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Inventory</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="content">

    <select id="itemType" onchange="populateItem()">
        <option value='Computer'>  Computer</option>
        <option value='Monitor'>  Monitor</option>
        <option value='Phone'>  Phone</option>
        <option value='Printer'>  Printer</option>
    </select>
    <select id="itemSelect"></select>

    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Whenever I run my program it will not set itemSelect to show the innerHTML of the selected option. It takes the value as I used google developer to check itemSelect.value but will not show actual selected text. The above code is my js file and my html file. It is pulling items value from another js file, but i am sure it is pulling values correctly as i can see options and also select them, changing itemSelected.value. It is just whatever the default selection is, it will not produce just the visual text on the select element until a different option in the select element is chosen.

Comment: What is `items`? You use it as an array but it doesn't come from anywhere, as far as I can see.

Comment: The code doesn't set the value attribute of the select at all, it inserts options, assuming the condition is true, which is impossible to infer from the posted code ?

Comment: it is a json file. the issue is strictly with updating the text of the select element, as if i select second option in dropdown, it changes text , and i can then select 1st option and it will take text then, but not when i change item type initially

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `selectedIndex` property of the select element again because you messed with it's innerHtml.

Just set it like:

```
itemSel.selectedIndex = "1";
```

The value should be the index of the option element you want to be selected.

Here is the info for selectedIndex: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp

Comment: where do you recommend I put this line.  I placed it at end of populateItem() and it no longer allowed my program to pull the information from items array.

Comment: the only thing this does is change itemSelect.value, is not producing the actual text of the option on the select element.

Comment: By that do you mean you see the select element with a blank option but if you click on the dropdown icon, you see your options there? Or the problem is the itemSelect element is completely empty?

Comment: Why do you need the reload() function?

Comment: I see the options and i know the value is taken, but it will not display the itemSelect elements text until a different opption than default is selected.  and the reload() function was an attempt to force text to appear

Comment: I see, try adding `container.selectedIndex = "0";` as the last line inside the reload() function.

Comment: Although you shouldn't need to do that reload(), the problem is the contents of the select element were regenerated dynamically and that causes it to 'deselect' any options, you just need to make it select an option again, by setting 0 to the selectedIndex property, you are selecting the first option, and that should be enough for the select element to be displayed correctly.

Comment: put it as the last line of my populateItem() function and it did not work, it is changing the value, but not the text of the select element.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by creating a div to house the select element, then just clearing the div and createElement(select) attached to an onchange event.